# Master thesis topic connected with WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-codecs

I am student and I'd like to write my master thesis about WebRTC. I wish that it would be connected with media (e.g. video codecs). Unfortunately the only supported video codec in WebRTC is V8. During last couple of days I was searching documentation and internet and I could not find anything which would be suitable for master thesis. Maybe you guys, have some interesting ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [WebRTC google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/discuss-webrtc/video%2420codec%5d) topics filtered with *video codec*.

Because I wrote my bachelor thesis about WebRTC & SIP I know that WebRTC supported video codec isn't only VP8. It pepends on the codec availibility at the clients (for example two browsers).

The process of [Session Description Protocol (SDP) exchange](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-nandakumar-rtcweb-sdp-01.html) takes care of the finally used media codecs.

Currently there isn't a lot of documentation or litature of WebRTC. I got the most information out of different [RFCs at the IETF](http://www.ietf.org/rfc.html).